# Adding pagination to wordpress amp-wp plugin

Tags: wordpress, amp-html

I am using the WordPress AMP plugin by Automattic and trying to figure out how to keep my pagination functioning. I have many very long posts and the plugin is converting all my post to single AMP pages and removing the pagination that is implemented using the  comment block that is available in WordPress. This is the code I use for the Desktop and Responsive version of my blog but it doesn't work on the AMP pages. Any help functions or edits to my pagination function I can make to get my pagination working correctly again would be great. I am also opening to editing the plugin if there is a fix that way.

```
function new_pagination($pages = '', $range = 1) {
    $showitems = ($range * 2)+1;
    global $paged, $page;

    if(empty($paged)) $paged = 1;

    if(empty($page)) $page = 1;

    if($pages == '') {
        global $wp_query, $numpages;
        if ( is_single() ) { 
            $pages = $numpages;
        }else{
            $pages = $wp_query->max_num_pages;
        }
        if(!$pages) {
            $pages = 1;
        }
    }

    if(1 != $pages) {
        echo "<div class='pagination'><ul>";
        if ( is_single() ) { 
            if(($page > 2 && $page > $range+1 && $showitems < $pages) && ($page > 1 && $showitems < $pages)) {
                echo "<li class='mobile-show'><a href='".get_permalink().--$page."/'>Prev</a></li>";
                echo "<li class='first'><a href='".get_permalink()."'>First</a></li>";
                $page++;
            }else{
                if($page > 1 && $showitems < $pages) {
                    echo "<li><a href='".get_permalink().--$page."/'>Prev</a></li>";
                    $page++;
                }
                if($page > 2 && $page > $range+1 && $showitems < $pages) echo "<li class='first'><a href='".get_permalink()."'>First</a></li>";

            }
        }else{
            if(($paged > 2 && $paged > $range+1 && $showitems < $pages) && ($paged > 1 && $showitems < $pages)) {
                echo "<li class='mobile-show'><a href='".get_pagenum_link($paged - 1)."'>Prev</a></li>";
                echo "<li class='first'><a href='".get_pagenum_link(1)."'>First</a></li>";
            }else{
                if($paged > 1 && $showitems < $pages) echo "<li class='mobile-show'><a href='".get_pagenum_link($paged - 1)."'>Prev</a></li>";
                if($paged > 2 && $paged > $range+1 && $showitems < $pages) echo "<li class='first'><a href='".get_pagenum_link(1)."'>First</a></li>";
            }
        }
        for ($i=1; $i <= $pages; $i++) {
            if ( is_single() ) { 
                if (1 != $pages &&( !($i >= $page+$range+1 || $i <= $page-$range-1) || $pages <= $showitems )) {
                    echo ($page == $i)? "<li class='active'><span class='current'>".$i."</span></li>":"<li><a href='".get_permalink()."".$i."/' class='inactive' >".$i."</a></li>";
                }
            }else{
                if (1 != $pages &&( !($i >= $paged+$range+1 || $i <= $paged-$range-1) || $pages <= $showitems )) {
                    echo ($paged == $i)? "<li class='active'><span class='current'>".$i."</span></li>":"<li><a href='".get_pagenum_link($i)."' class='inactive' >".$i."</a></li>";
                }
            }
        }
        if ( is_single() ) { 
            if(($page < $pages-1 && $page+$range-1 < $pages && $showitems < $pages) && ($page < $pages && $showitems < $pages)) {
                echo "<li class='last'><a href='".get_permalink().$pages."/'>Last</a></li>";
                echo "<li class='mobile-show'><a href='".get_permalink().++$page."/'>Next</a></li>";
            }else {
                if ($page < $pages-1 && $page+$range-1 < $pages && $showitems < $pages) echo "<li class='last'><a href='".get_permalink().$pages."/'>Last</a></li>";
                if ($page < $pages && $showitems < $pages) echo "<li class='mobile-show'><a href='".get_permalink().++$page."/'>Next</a></li>";
            }
        }else{
            if(($paged < $pages-1 && $paged+$range-1 < $pages && $showitems < $pages) && ($paged < $pages && $showitems < $pages)) {
                echo "<li class='last'><a href='".get_pagenum_link($pages)."'>Last</a></li>";
                echo "<li class='mobile-show'><a href='".get_pagenum_link($paged + 1)."'>Next</a></li>";
            }else {
                if ($paged < $pages-1 && $paged+$range-1 < $pages && $showitems < $pages) echo "<li class='last'><a href='".get_pagenum_link($pages)."'>Last</a></li>";
                if ($paged < $pages && $showitems < $pages) echo "<li class='mobile-show'><a href='".get_pagenum_link($paged + 1)."'>Next</a></li>";
            }
        }

        echo "</ul></div>\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with Wordpress with AMP plugin but upon checking this [issue](https://github.com/Automattic/amp-wp/issues/276), pagination is supported in wordpress amp-wp plugin. You may also want to check this pull request [#313](https://github.com/Automattic/amp-wp/pull/313/commits/3258e7d9b001bfe9481455146aca3ccfa48a2440) for additional information about the support of pagination in the plugin.

Comment: Yeah, i looked through that but it is only for the homepage. I contacted the plugin authors and they said that they dont have a timeline for implementing pagination. That is why I asked on here to see if anyone is familiar with the plugin that could help me add the functionality until the plugin authors get around to it.

Comment: Maybe we can use CSS similar to how some image carousels have a click to show caption, have it click to show that `<div>` and hide the rest.

Comment: I know it can be done via this link:

https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/components/amp-live-list

I just dont know how to implement this into the plugin